# Added a new page but it doesn't show when viewing website

Tags: wordpress

Just started learning wordpress today and I'm following a tutorial.

I've added a new page called "home", with no section titles and a one column layout.

I hit publish everything seemed fine, but when I go to view the website the page can't be found. When on the tutorial page doing the exact same steps. The page can be found and it has links to the page

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming question.

Comment: So sorry I didn't know this comment was against the rules. I don't used this website regularly. I didn't know there was rules. Again very sorry if I've offended you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you don't see it in the menu - did you add the page to the menu? it doesn't do it automatically

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by that. I've just copied what the tutorial says. What do you mean by "menu"